# Jquery doesnt work after loading content via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

I am new with java script. The code I have for deleting table row works fine when table already exists in the page but it doesnt work if I load table from another page by ajax call.. please help me to solve this.. java script is here

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('table#delTable td a.delete').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var data = 'id=' + id ;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "delete_row.php",
                   data: data,
                   cache: false,

                   success: function()
                   {
                        parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });                
        }
    });

    // style the table with alternate colors
    // sets specified color for every odd row
    $('table#delTable tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
});
```

html code

```
<table id="delTable">       


    <tr id="ripon">
        <td align="left">Ipsum</td>
        <td align="center">19</td>
        <td align="center">17</td>
        <td align="center"><a href="#" class="delete" style="color:#FF0000;"><img alt="" align="absmiddle" border="0" src="img/delete.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rukon">
        <td align="left">Dolor</td>
        <td align="center">55</td>
        <td align="center">12</td>
        <td align="center"><a href="#" class="delete" style="color:#FF0000;"><img alt="" align="absmiddle" border="0" src="img/delete.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sumon">
        <td align="left">Sit</td>
        <td align="center">11</td>
        <td align="center">18</td>
        <td align="center"><a href="#" class="delete" style="color:#FF0000;"><img alt="" align="absmiddle" border="0" src="img/delete.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="mamun">
        <td align="left">Amet</td>
        <td align="center">29</td>
        <td align="center">27</td>
        <td align="center"><a href="#" class="delete" style="color:#FF0000;"><img alt="" align="absmiddle" border="0" src="img/delete.png" /></a></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution for this is to use "Delegated Events".
For more information, see [jQuery's `on` docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$("body").on("click", "table#delTable td a.delete", function(event){
  // insert your code here
});
```

Note: while I called `on` on `body`, you can call it on something "closer" to the table, if it's going to be there when the page loads (or more specifically, when you make the `on` call).